# What is the order of acidity for hydrogens in primary, secondary and tertiary alkanes, alkenes, and cycloalkanes

Tags: acid-base, bond, reactivity, hydrocarbons, hydrogen

The bond dissociation energies of C-H bonds in alkanes, alkenes and aromatic compounds decrease in the following order: primary > secondary > tertiary > allylic > benzylic.
The weaker the bond, the lower the bond dissociation energies. Does the acidity of primary, secondary, tertiary, allylic and benzylic hydrogens follow the same order?

Comment: No, it correlates rather with how well carboanion is stabilised.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43468/which-proton-in-cyclohexene-is-the-most-acidic