# Strongest overlap among s–s, p–p, s–p

Tags: bond, orbitals, atoms, atomic-structure

So, I was wondering, when overlap of orbitals takes place, among s–s, s–p, p–p which type of overlapping is stronger?

Because in s–s more volume is being used in overlap, but the electron density is less; whereas in p–p electron density is more, but overlap is less; or s–p because it has partially both the effects?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/81456/44877

Comment: Looks like a repeat Q to me. But there may be more to add to the answer to the question linked by @Tan Yong Boon

Comment: I'm not talking about hybridised orbitals , more like in H-H and F-F type

Comment: @user232243 sigma bonds are not reliant on hybridization. The assignment as sigma, pi, delta solely relies on the symmetry, not the constituent orbitals. The latter can be used to find the symmetry involved.