# Which would be more acidic, benzene or cyclohexane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

If benzene were to donate a hydrogen ion, then could the negative charge still be delocalised around the ring? Wouldn't that break aromaticity and thus destabilise the molecule?

Answer (score 3):

See: [Relative acidities of alkanes, alkenes, and alkynes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32341/16683). Essentially the same explanation holds here, as benzene carbons are sp<sup>2</sup>-hybridised.

The newly formed lone pair is in a σ-type orbital (blue) which does not overlap with the π system (red), hence no delocalisation is possible.

[image: Sigma and pi systems of benzene]