# The most acidic hydrogen among ethane, ethene, ethyne and allene

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, resonance, inductive-effect

Among

$$\ce{CH3-CH3}\qquad\ce{CH2=CH2}\qquad\ce{HC≡CH}\qquad\ce{CH2=C=CH2}$$

I need to find out the one having highest acidic hydrogen.

As per my observations, there are two equivalent resonating structures possible in case of conjugate base of $\ce{CH2=C=CH2}.$ However, the correct answer is given as $\ce{HC≡CH}$ due to inductive effect of sp hybridization of carbon.

But the priority order in determining stability of a conjugate base is:

1. Aromaticity
2. Number of equivalent resonating structures
3. Resonance
4. Hyperconjugation
5. Inductive effect

As such, the correct answer should have been the *allene*. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Does the downvoter have any gut to comment?

Comment: Related: [Relative acidities of alkanes, alkenes, and alkynes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32341/relative-acidities-of-alkanes-alkenes-and-alkynes).

Comment: I did not downvote, but likely some people will if they seem to see a homework problem with no/too little work input from the asker.  You might want to look at the link given be andselisk for some ideas, as well.

Comment: This "priority order" is hardly a law of nature. In my opinion, instead of trying to force everything into a fixed order, it's a better idea to get more experience with various functional group pKa's so that you have a better idea of how much each factor affects the pKa. That takes time. You might think that memorising some order is a quick shortcut to the top, and maybe it *does* work for quite a few cases, but I fear that this sort of approach comes with the risk of having to unlearn wrong things later on.

Comment: But that's just me. If you have to learn this sort of thing, it's ok, just make sure to take it with a pinch of salt. Especially because these sort of orders were worked out *precisely by observing the pKa's of various compounds*, so using them to predict pKa's is a *little* bit like circular logic. **TLDR:** *Models only work in the contexts in which they were developed.*

Comment: @OscarLanzi well, this isn't exactly a homework problem. I was trying this on my own and did my calculations and have also drawn conclusions accordingly as given in the question. It just gets irritating when you've genuinely asked a question and someone out of the blue votes it down without telling what to fix, you know -_-

Comment: I agree with @orthocresol. The stability order here would be $\mathrm{sp \gt sp^2 \gt sp^3}$. In allene, $\ce{H}$ is on $\mathrm{sp^2}$ carbon, so most stable carbanion would be that from acetylene.

Comment: @andselisk I know the order of acidity of different types of hybridization. Was just confused about the priority order :(

Comment: @orthocresol thanks, that way it works. But, I was wondering about the priority order. So asked this question. But, I was really disappointed when someone voted it down without citing a reason :(

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Thank you so much. Seriously, I was just pissed of due to that downvote for this question. Sorry :(

Comment: To paraphrase @orthocresol, models work insofar as they reflect reality, but you may discover that a specific model that you frequently use does not cover a specific case, or use case or whatever. Models explain/predict some features in some cases, but that doesn't mean they are general or right or anything.

Answer (score -1):

The inductive effect will always make the stronger acidic compound, especially with an sp hybridization as it will ultimately stabilize the electrophile best in solution. Though resonance will also contribute to the stability, a structure similar to allene will have more resonance as it will have more bonds focused in one area so close to the electrophilic site.

I think you over resonance, its an easy mistake, but my notes from Orgo I show that the difference in pKa from an sp2 to an sp hybridization are roughly a factor of 2.

TL:DR, Induction beats resonance.

Comment: But in most of the cases that I've seen in these types of problem, resonance is prioritized over induction :(